# On the absolute difference of the Laplacian eigenvalues of an unbalanced signed graph and its underlying graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, spectral-graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $\Sigma=(G,\sigma)$ be an unbalanced signed graph with the underlying connected graph $G=(V,E)$ and $\sigma:E\rightarrow \{-1,1\}$, the signing function. Let the Laplacian eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ and $G$ be ordered non-increasingly as $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge\lambda_n>0$ and $\mu_1\ge \mu_2\ge\cdots\ge\mu_n=0$, respectively. Then can we prove that $\lvert \lambda_i-\mu_i\rvert\le 2\sqrt{n-2}$ for $i=2,\cdots,n-1$? (Please focus on the values of $i$). Recall that the Laplacian matrices for the signed graph is $L(\Sigma)=D(G)-A(\Sigma)$ where $D(G)$ is the diagonal matrix of the degrees of the vertices and $A(\Sigma)$ is the adjacency matrix. Also note that $G$ can be taken as a balanced signed graph with its edge signs as all positive ones.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the definition of the signings and how you're defining the signed Laplacians, but if $G$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices, and $\sigma\equiv -1$, then isn't $\lambda_1(\Sigma)=2n-2$ while $\lambda_1(G)=n$?

Comment: @ Jason You are right. Sorry for taking $i$ from 1 to n-1. It must be from 2 to n-1 instead. I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: So what happens if you just take the disjoint union of complete graphs on $n/2$ nodes and take $\sigma \equiv -1$? I doubt you can generically do better than what you can get from the Wielandt-Hoffman inequalities. (Also, I would prefer not to get emails about MO questions unless it's really important...)

Comment: @Jason Sorry again. My underlying graph $G $ is connected.

Comment: Okay, so just add a single edge between the clusters. This changes the eigenvalues by at most 2.